# HammerJS pan either forces horizontal event on a vertical scroll, or disables scrolling all together

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I'm making an animation for a flip-pagey effect on a site.

I need to use HammerJS pan to measure the distance the fingers travelled, swipe does not support this apparently.

However it breaks at a very specific bug:

https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/1056

My pan left and right works flawlessly, but when I want to "scroll" down the page with a finger, it breaks. The page jumps and thinks its a left pan event.

Has anyone figured out how to have a scrollable element and still have pan left and right? Cant see this is fixed in hammerjs.

If I add various fixes like:

```
        var swipe = new Hammer(page);

        swipe.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
```

Vertical touch scrolling does not work at all.

Heres my code:

```
            var page = document.getElementById("main-page");
            var swipe = new Hammer(page);

            swipe.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });

            var width = (50 / 100) * page.offsetWidth;
            var language = $('body').attr('lang');

            delete Hammer.defaults.cssProps.userSelect;
            swipe.on('pan', function (e) {
                //4 = left
                if (e.direction === 4) {
                    if(document.getElementById("prevpagebutton")){
                        page.style.transform = 'translateX(' + e.deltaX + 'px)';
                        if(e.distance > width/3){
                            $('#snackbar').length === 0 ? JS.common_functions.snackBar(3000,'<i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>', 0) : '';
                            if(e.distance > width){
                                document.getElementById("prevpagebutton").click();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#snackbar').length === 0 ? JS.common_functions.snackBar(3000, JS.common_functions.translate('startOfBook', 
JS.language.navigation, language), 0, 0) : '';
                    }
                }
                    //2 = right
                if (e.direction === 2) {
                    if(document.getElementById("nextpagebutton")) {
                        page.style.transform = 'translateX(' + e.deltaX + 'px)';
                        if(e.distance > width/3){

                            $('#snackbar').length === 0 ? JS.common_functions.snackBar(2000,'<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>', 0) : '';
                            if(e.distance > width){
                                document.getElementById("nextpagebutton").click();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#snackbar').length === 0 ? JS.common_functions.snackBar(3000, JS.common_functions.translate('endOfBook', 
JS.language.navigation, language), 0, 0) : '';
                    }
                }
                if(e.eventType === 4){
                    page.style.transform = 'translateX(' + 0 + 'px)';
                }
            });
```